# Wordpress: Display multiple static pages on one page (Single Page website)

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

what is the best practice to turn a single-page website into a wordpress site? How should I render the different pages in ONE file (front-page.php, e.g.), appearing one after another?
Each section on the page should be a different wordpress (static) page. One template that renders other templates?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

in the index.php file make each section a post query of the page name.

```
<section>
<?php query_posts('pagename=youpagename'); if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div>the coontent etc.</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I used a while back. Might help you out.
Make sure when you test it the ID's match pages in the backend.

```
<section id="usp" class="clearfix">

    <?php

        $pages = get_pages('include=11,212,15,17&sort_column=menu_order');

        $count = 0;

        foreach($pages as $page)

        {

        $content = $page->post_excerpt;

    ?>

    <div class="column">

        <div class="inner">

            <h2><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>"><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a></h2>

            <div class="usp-excerpt"><p><?php echo $content ?></p></div>

            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" title="<?php echo $page->post_title ?>" class="usp-readmore">More&hellip;</a>

        </div> <!-- end inner -->

    </div> <!-- end column -->

    <?php } ?>

</section> <!-- end usp -->
```